# jQuery fadeTo and fadeIn not working anywhere except for JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, fadein, fadeto

I can't seem to get even a simple fade-in effect to work on chrome or safari - but it works perfectly well with jsfiddle (Chrome 19.0.1084.56 & Safari 5.1.7). I'm also not getting any javascript errors to work off of. Previously I had tried

> $("#fade").hide().fadeIn

which also worked fine in jsfiddle but not in my file. Interestingly, fadeOut works alright when I use it.

Here's my code below - does it work alright for you? If you have any idea as to why it isn't  for me, please let me know!

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Wheee jQuery!</title>

<!-- jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#fade").fadeTo(2000, 1);

</script>

<!-- css -->
<style type="text/css">
#fade{
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="fade">
lalala
</div>   

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(function(){/*mycode*/});` (incoming 8 answers) By default JSFiddle code is ran on window load, not in the head unwrapped.

Comment: You have called the `fadeTo` method before the div is rendered either move the call below `<div id="fade">
lalala
</div> ` or call the method inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, JSFiddle has `OnLoad` selected which runs the code found within the `JavaScript` panel within a `body.onload` event. Your code on the other hand runs the code unwrapped in the header. To simulate that situation in JSFiddle, select `No Wrap` instead of `OnLoad` and your code will all of a sudden not work, just like on your server.

To solve this problem, wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fade").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Sample of JSFiddle with No Wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/3cXvL/1/

An alternative solution is to place your code after the div that it needs to affect.

```
<div id="fade"></div>
<script>
    $("#fade").fadeIn(2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hope that downvote wasn't yours as I had already started on the fiddle when you commented ;} And it's good to post the full code for search purposes.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall It wasn't, I voted for yours, was just too lazy to post it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

"Use `$(document).ready(function(){/*mycode*/});` (incoming 8 answers)" - Kevin.

Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/3cXvL/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fade").fadeTo(2000, 1);
});
```

Comment: Should Select Kevins answer as accepted. Welcome to StackOverflow!